# Verify whether the file path contains particular String or not using java

Tags: java, file

I have one file path which is populated using File interface:-

```
File folder = new File("C:\\Program Files\\SmartBear\\ReadyAPI-2.2.0\\bin")
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
File fOut = listOfFiles[0];

System.out.println(fOut)
```

It prints all the files inside bin folder. lets say, actions, ext, listeners

Now, I need to verify using if else statement whether the files inside the bin folder contains the particular file I am searching for?

Can we do it using java?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Give it a try.

Comment: try with `FilenameFilter`

Comment: Could you please suggest with code also? How to use this methods or interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general example based on `String.contains()`:

```
String expectedString = "PartOfFilename";
File folder = new File("/path/to/directory");

File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.getName().contains(expectedString)) {
        //matching file found
    }
}
```